# How can I enter a Google Authenticator Account/Key combination with a URL?

Tags: google-authenticator

I need to enter a key into Google Authenticator but my camera on my smart phone is fuzzy so it can't read QR codes !!!

I can read the code using other devices. The code evaluates to something like this: http://itunes-store/google-authenticator/id000000000?mt=0 where the 0's are numbers.

When I open Google Authenticator I can either take a picture of a QR code (which does not work) or I can enter an "Account/Key" combination. How does the URL above equate to an Account/Key combination?

Comment: There is no "account/key" combo. The "account" is just a label.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to type code instead of scanning. There is a link below the qr that gives you an option to type in the code by hand.